# Linked list as an argument to a function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

The program does not print the list's values as it is intended to. It prints something that's gotta be a memory address imo. I've been trying to find the solution solo, but to no avail thus far. I would appreciate some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t * head);

void main()
{
    node_t * head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (head == NULL)
        return 1;
    head->val = 1;
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->val = 2;
    head->next->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->next->val = 3;
    head->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->next->next->val = 18;
    head->next->next->next->next = NULL;

    print_list(&head);
    system("pause");
}

void print_list(node_t * head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

The aforementioned problem was resolved thanks to your inputs. Thank you very much! However, a new issue occurred. Wanting to add a new element to the list, I added a few lines of code. Unfortunately, the wanted result is not printed and the program is terminated abruptly. Here's the new code:

```
    head->next->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->next->next->next->val = 5556;
    head->next->next->next->next->next = NULL;
    node_t * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) 
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->val = 32;
    current->next->next = NULL;
    printf("%d\n", current->next->val);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Your function `print_list` expects an argument of type  `node_t *` but you are passing `node_t **`. Change  `print_list(&head);` to `print_list(head);`

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Oh, so it was that simple. Thank you everyone for your help! I've just started playing with pointers so there's a great deal for me to learn.

Answer (score 5):

Note that your function `void print_list(node_t * head);` expects a parameter of type `node_t *` but you are passing parameter of type `node_t **`.
Change `print_list(&head);` to `print_list(head);`
`head` is of type `node_t *` while `&head` is of type `node_t **`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `print_list(&head)` function to `print_list(head)`.

```
print_list(&head);
```

to

```
print_list(head);
```

function `void print_list(node_t * head)` accepts single reference pointer. But your passing `**head` to the `print_list` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print_list` function is called using    `print_list(&head);` , however head is already a pointer to a node.

This means that the print_list function is actually receiving a pointer to a pointer to a node, or `node_t **`. As such, when you try to print the values of the pointer you will see something that appears to be a memory address. To fix this, just pass in the head of the list using    `print_list(head);`